# XPATH With Dot/Period in Text Returns No Results When created as a variable but works if using a literal

Tags: xpath

Total Newbie learning while doing.

I am trying to extract text from an Article. The only hook I could get was that each of the items I wanted started with a number followed by a period/dot.

The problem I am having is that if I use a string with the period/dot embedded the xpath query returns a value. If I try to create the string by assembling the sting so I can vary the number I get nothing in the response

So this works:

```
baker = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/article/div[2]/div[5]/div[*]/p[starts-with(text(),"62.")]/text()')
```

but this fails with a syntax error:

```
nose = '/html/body/div[1]/main/article/div[2]/div[5]/div[*]/p[starts-with(text(),'
tail = ")]/text()')"
for i in range (2):
    node = '"' + str(62) + '"'
    path = nose + node + tail
    baker = tree.xpath(path)
```

for comparison purposes:
string copy / paste returns a value

```
/html/body/div[1]/main/article/div[2]/div[5]/div[*]/p[starts-with(text(),"62.")]/text()')
```

string assembled as above returns nothing

```
'/html/body/div[1]/main/article/div[2]/div[5]/div[*]/p[starts-with(text(),"62")]/text()\')'
```

I think it has something to do with the back slash at the end of the assembled string but I can't seem to get rid of it

Comment: the double quotes in the nose variable are there because the sting has a single quote in the middle. If I just use single quotes python errors on the odd number of single quote marks

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand:

```
tail = ")]/text()')"
```

Why not just:

```
tail = ')]/text()'
```

Comment: OP: did this answer helped you?